# Disable DataSheet view only on one specific ListView

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, datasheet

I have setup a specific ListView with all the columns I need.

I need to disable the Datasheet view on this ListView (called SubmittersList) then I need to have Datasheet view enabled on my other ListView (called ApproversList). This is the reason I cant untick the Datasheet checkbox in the list settings as there are two views.

I am guessing there is a way I can do this through a content editor on AllItems.aspx with some javascript/jquery but I am struggling to start with the code.

Any suggestions would be must appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a Datasheet view (ApproversList) and then disable Datasheet view in list settings. This way, the ApproversList will be still displayed as Datasheet but you will not be able to switch to DS view in other views.

Basically, the property Datasheet (Specify whether the datasheet can be used to bulk edit data on this list.) in list settings just enables/disables the button in ribbon.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Your words "..disable Datasheet view.." is too general.

Comment: List settings -> Advanced -> Quick Edit = No

Comment: The OP said "...struggling to to start with the code".  What value using either SOM or CSOM can one programmatically change a property on the `SPList` class to achieve the goal?